# Are there infinitely many primitive Pythagorean $n$-tuples?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

Let's define a Pythagorean $n$-tuple ($n \geq 3$) as a tuple of distinct natural numbers $(x_1, ... , x_{n-1}, y)$, such that $x_1^{n-1} + ... + x_{n-1}^{n-1} = y^{n-1}$. Let's call a Pythagorean $n$-tuple primitive if $GCD(x_1, ... , x_{n-1}, y) = 1$

It is a rather well known fact, that there are infinitely many primitive Pythagorean triples. Indeed, $(2k(k + 1))^2 + (2k + 1)^2 = (2k(k + 1) + 1)^2$ $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.

But is it true that $\forall n \geq 3$ there are infinitely many primitive Pythagorean $n$-tuples?

No construction, similar to the one used for $n = 3$ comes to my mind for arbitrary $n$...

Comment: You could start with a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple

Comment: I presume you don't consider $0$ a natural number

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, no, I don't.

Comment: You can start looking here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_sum_of_powers_conjecture For n=4: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes and for n=5 here around display (100): https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html

Comment: Long story short, for some $n$ we don't know if there is _one_ such tuple.

Comment: Interesting question, but it would be improved by avoiding the non-standard use of "Pythagorean", which in the context of Diophantine equations is normally understood to mean a sum of squares equal to a square, and not an equation in higher powers.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=4$ we have this [1] infinite parametrised set of solutions for 1:
$$(9t^4)^3 + (-9t^4 \mp 3t)^3 + (\pm 9t^3 + 1)^3 = 1$$

[1] Kurt Mahler, Note On Hypothesis K of Hardy and Littlewood, Journal of the London Mathematical Society **11** (1936), 136–138.

Answer (score 0):

"OP" required numerical solution's to the below equation:

$x_1^{n-1} + x_2^{n-1}+x_3^{n-1}............. + x_{n-1}^{n-1} = y^{n-1}$ --(1)

For, $n=6$ we get:

$x_1^{5} + x_2^{5}+x_3^{5}+x_4^{5}+ x_{5}^{5} = y^{5}$

example is:  $(19,43,46,47,67)^5=(72)^5$

---

For, $n=5$

$x_1^{4} + x_2^{4}+x_3^{5}+x_4^{4}= y^{4}$

example is:    $(30,120,272,315)^4=(353)^4$

---

For, $n=4$

$x_1^{3} + x_2^{3}+x_3^{3}= y^{3}$

example is:      $(3,4,5)^3=(6)^3$

---

For, $n=3$

$x_1^{2} + x_2^{2}= y^{4}$

example is:      $(3,4)^2=(5)^2$

Note: There are numerical solution's for equation (1) above, for

degree seven & eight but none yet for degree six.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't think you understood my question correctly. I asked not for numerical solutions but for a theoretical proof that there are finitely many/infinitely many of them.

Comment: Also note that none of the higher exponent answers are primitive in the sense that in each example, at least two of the numbers have a common factor $>1$, which I read OP's question to require.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is still an open problem, wheather (k -1 -n) has finite or infinite solutions. Where k is degree of the equation & n is number of terms on the RHS. Mathematician Titus pizzas wrote an article some ten year's ago. And he ask's the same question. His Webpage link is given below.
[ http://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas ]. Click on algebraic identities. Click on Ramanujan pages. Click on article #15, Euler's conjecture.

Comment: A quick computer program shows that all testable powers appear in 'tuples as fast as the screen can display them. Remember the $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$ joke? I addressed 2nd power because he wanted Pythagorean n-tuples.

Comment: @Poetasis. I think you are missing the point. The question posted above is talking about equations with different exponents like (3,4,5,6,7,8,9). Also for degree two you are only allowed two term's on the LHS. Your answer is about degree two &  has not addressed the other exponent's like the cubics & the quadric's .

Answer (score -1):

The answer is yes. For every side C in a primitive, a side A can be found in another primitive. For example, $(3,4,5)\rightarrow (5,12,13)\rightarrow (13,84,85)$ and these can be joined to make a single 4-dimensional figure. Let's reason this backward. If we have $5,12,13$, we can replace $5^2$ with $3^2+4^2$ and not affect the equation. Moving forward, $\quad 3^3+4^2+12^2+84^2=85^2.\quad$ One formula (mine) for generating Pythagorean triples is:
$$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\qquad B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\qquad C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2$$

It creates sets within the subset of triples where $GCD(A,B,C)=(2m-1)^2, m\in\mathbb{N}$ as shown here
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5   &  k=6  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61 & 13,84,85 \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 & 45,108,117 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 & 85,132,157 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 & 133,156,205 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 & 189,180,261 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

If you have any side C, you can find a match in $Set_1$––side-A in $Set_1$ contains all odd numbers greater than one and all members of $Set_1$ are primitive––and sometimes elsewhere. If we solve the $A$-function for $k$, we can find a matching $A$, if it exists, with defined finite search limits. Any of the $n$-values that yield an integer $k$ gives us a triple.

$$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\quad\longrightarrow\quad k_A=\frac{A-(2n-1)^2}{2(2n-1)}\quad\text{where}\quad 1\le n\le\biggl\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{A+1}}{2}\biggr\rfloor $$ for example, beginning with $\qquad F(2,4)=(33,56,65)\qquad$ we have

$$\\ A=65\quad \longrightarrow \quad  1\le n\le\bigg\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{65+1}}{2}\bigg\rfloor=4  \quad\text{and we find} \quad n \in \{1,3\}\quad \Rightarrow \quad  k\in\{32,4\}\\ $$
$$F(1,32)=(65,2112,2113)\qquad F(3,4)=(65,72,97)$$

Here, we have already created a new tuple where
$$33^2+56^2+72^2=97^2$$
How about 
$$(3,4,5)\&(5,12,13)\&(13,84,85)\&(85,132,157)\&(157,12324,12325)\\\Longrightarrow 3^2+4^2+12^2+84^2+132^2+12324^2=12325^2$$

It is easy to see that the process can continue to infinity.

Comment: In my math hobby, I have played with the idea of extending the Pythagorean theorem in such a way that, for any power $(p)$, there are $(p+1)$ terms where $$x_1^p+x_2^p+p_3^p...x_p^p=x_{p+1}^p$$
and I have found that it works for powers $3,4,5$. Perhaps a proof of sorts could be developed from this observation.